# Make WebSocket sending non-blocking

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, stomp, spring-websocket

Jetty uses **org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.BlockingWriteCallback** to send messages over websocket. If the client is "slow" then this blocking write may experience hangs (see e.g. here https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/272#issuecomment-290910610)

I have a successfull simulation of slow client using Jetty+Spring+Spring's Websocket Client.

I would like to "send and forget" websocket messages, so if client is slow (for whatever confirmation it tries to do), this does not affect resolution of BrokerWriteCallback. What would be the best way to achieve that with Jetty (configuration or source code edit?)

Present Jetty version 9.3.11.v20160721 used with Spring 4.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty has [slow server](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/SlowServerTest.java) and [slow client](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/SlowClientTest.java) tests already.

There's no such thing as "send and forget", as that implies infinite buffering.

There are non-blocking send options, but it is **strongly** encouraged that you pay attention to the `Futures` or `Callbacks` to know if the local endpoint has successfully sent that message (or not).

> Hint: don't send another message to a RemoteEndpoint if the prior one hasn't succeeded yet (you have network congestion decisions to deal with).

Failure to pay attention to the `Futures` or `Callbacks` *will* trigger memory errors (OOM).

See [`RemoteEndpoint`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html):

- void [sendBytes](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendBytes-java.nio.ByteBuffer-org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WriteCallback-)(ByteBuffer data, WriteCallback callback)
- Future [sendBytesByFuture](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendBytesByFuture-java.nio.ByteBuffer-)(ByteBuffer data)
- void [sendString](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendString-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WriteCallback-)(String text, WriteCallback callback)
- Future [sendStringByFuture](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendStringByFuture-java.lang.String-)(String text)

If all of this seems overwhelming, consider using one of the many libraries built on top of websocket to manage all of this.

I would encourage you to look at the open source project [cometd.org](https://cometd.org/)

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate about problems you menion? Suppose I sendString with a callback. Will callback return when the client received the message, or when it was "written to network", but without some confirmation from a client? To be honest I do not know yet how exactly low-level communication works, and appreciate useful insights on this, too. If client "hangs" (fails to receive) then the thread is blocked. I want ideally that my program would be able to send data to other clients. Currently I use single-thread sending for certain reasons (only one thread gets to call Jetty)